# Objective-C iPhone data between classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is my situation. I have ViewController class A with a button that goes to TableViewController class B by doing the following.

```
- (void) goToClassB
{
    ViewControllerB *viewController =
    [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // Present view controller modally.
    if ([self
        respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I want to be able to have an array that can be accessed and edited by both class A and class B. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use plist for maintaining array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Array variable in Class B like:

```
@interface classB:NSObject
{
  NSMutableArray *arrayFromA;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)  NSMutableArray *arrayFromA;
```

Synthesize the variable.

And in this method pass the array like:

```
- (void) goToClassB
{
   ViewControllerB *viewController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   [viewController setArrayFromA:yourArray];
   // Present view controller modally.
   if ([self
     respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
     [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
      [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been very close but this finally did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSMutableArray in ViewControllerA and pass it to ViewControllerB after your allocation.

Comment: ViewControllerB NSMutableArray should be assign.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve Creating NSMutableArray And And Make it in Property assign in one of the class

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would, just as others point out, be simply passing the array to B by setting a property, but one other option would be to let B have a weak back reference to A. Thus you're always using the same array. This could be useful if A and B are changing the array at the same time.

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSArray *array;
@end 

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak)  ViewControllerA *viewControllerA;
@end 

/* When you're creating the ViewControllerB, do this: */
...
viewController.viewControllerA = self;
...

/* Use the array (From ViewControllerB) */

- (void)doSomethingWithTheArray
{
    self.viewControllerA.array = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mention that you want edit by both so.You can use application delegation for sharing app level variable. Check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Some code is here. In your app delegate class.

```
@interface YourDelegateClass:UIResponder
{
  NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)  NSMutableArray *array;
```

You can access that array from everywhere of your app class with this code

```
YourDelegateClass * delegate =[[UIApplication shareApplication]delegate];
yourclassa.array = delegate.array;
or yourclassb.array = delegate.array;
```

Note: your must **alloc** **delegate.array** on your prefer at class or your delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Create NSMutable array in view1 set property

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Create same array in viewB and set property and

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)  NSMutableArray *arrayB;
```

> @Synthesize that

Now at the time call viewB set value of array of viewA to viewB like this

```
ViewControllerB *viewController = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[viewController arrayB:array];
```